# Android: get only dimensions of the last rectangle in crop image from com.android.camera.action.CROP

Tags: android

I do not want to crop my image but rather just want the dimensions of the crop rectangle in the com.android.camera.action.CROP activity.

Is it possible or is there any code for this?